# PySpark: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'forEach'

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to get data from hdfs and iterate through each data to do an analysis on column _c1.

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/location/spark')
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sql = SQLContext(sc)

df = sql.read.csv('hdfs://namenode:9000/data.csv', header=False, inferSchema= True)
df.show() //works
df.forEach(lambda row: some_analyzer(row['_c1'])) // here is the error
```

But I am getting "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'forEach'" error.

I am new to PySpark. I am really looking forward for the help.

Comment: lowercase format.```foreach```.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see that. But even after that I get this error: ```_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.```

Comment: You cannot use your context inside of some_analyzer function

Comment: the analyzer is my custom function. _c1 consists of text that I am passing to a function to analyze. If that is not how it can be done please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `foreach`. All in lower case.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see that. But even after that I get this error:
```_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.```